# generating a string from a list or dictionary, how to treat first element differently?

Tags: python, list, loops

I am iterating over a list in a scripting language, here using python.

Say, I want to generate the string "list(), list(), list()".

Something gets added to the brackets of "list(....)" but that's not important.

I need to treat the first Element differently, as I don't add a comma (",") before the word list then.

My Code:

```
mydict = {"r": 34, "i": 56, "k" : 99} 

s = ""

listOfKeys = list()



firstInList = True

for key, value in mydict.iteritems() :

    listOfKeys.append(key)

    if firstInList:
       firstInList = False
    else:
       s += ","

    s += "list("

    # 
    # more code that is not relevant to the question ...
    #

    s += ")"

print s
```

Now when I have nested lists the approach gets messy. How do I solve that better in python?

Comment: So the about is `list() list(), list()` ?

Comment: I think the issue is that the OP is thinking that to put the commas in the right places, you add `", "` before every one except the first -- which is reasonable enough -- whereas most Python programmers would think of this as putting `", "` *between* all of the elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just keep your items in a list, then you can do `','.join(items)` which will do the right thing.

Comment: I'm just surprised by the fact that you _got_ what he was asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you'd just do a join.

```
",".join(listOfValues)
```

You could easily build a list of values, and then do that to it, to create the comma delimited string.  However, if you wanted to keep doing it this way, you could just check if the string is empty before appending to it.